# DensityPixel doesn't seem to work with ImageButton

Tags: android, pixel, dpi, image-scaling

For a game I have six buttons which look good on mdpi. The 4 left buttons are 100x100px:

[image: Scaling ok]

If I switch to hdpi, it looks like this:

[image: Scaling not ok]

The xml looks like this (I omitted all but one button to keep it simple):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gameContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <com.mydomain.mygame.game.GameSurface
            android:id="@+id/gameSurface"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/background_game" >
        </com.mydomain.mygame.game.GameSurface>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/controlButtonContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/button_left"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/button_left"
                android:background="@drawable/control_button" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/emptyBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

These attempts didn't work:
I tried to use **100dp** instead of **wrap_content**. I tried **src** instead of **background** as well as I tried different **scaleType** attributes.

Probably I could calculate the scaling factor in code, but I can't imagine that this is the proper way to do that. Why does it not scaled automatically, because what are **dp** then for? So how can I configure the right ratio in xml?

Comment: In WHICH FOLDER/S did you put your images (by the way: **src** doesn't scale, while **background** does)? Are they properly scaled to the resolution/s (because **dpi matter**!)? To configure different dimensions for resolutions you could use the dimens.xml file (or do it in Java), but this is not the case.

Comment: It seems you're using TABLETS, which have a different ruleset for naming the drawable folders.

Comment: @ArtooDetoo It's just in drawable folder. I don't want special sizes for the buttons. I just want it to have the right ratio.

Comment: **drawable** is for **mdpi** resources (160 dpi), mostly for **PHONES**. **TABLETS** follow different rules for drawable folder naming (i.e.: **drawable-sw1080dp-xhdpi** for a tablet which has a 1920*1080 resolution at 320 dpi) from Android 3.2+. To support earlier Android version TABLES, you have to specify the old small, normal, large and xlarge modifiers for drawable (i.e.: **drawable-xlarge**). Refer to the links neeni suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please avoid use of specific size like 100dp . Try to use WRAP_CONTENT or MATCH_PARENT . and for different different screen sizes please use drawable-folders like drawable-hdpi and drawable-mdpi etc .  And Put corrosponding images of   android:background="@drawable/control_button" in all its specific folders .

Refer these linkes for multiple screen sizes : 
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html

Comment: the drawable folder is the default folder, so why should I make different sizes for different folders when I don't need it? I don't understand this. Moreover, as I said, wrap_content doesn't work either.

Comment: I placed now a bigger image in an drawable-xhdpi folder. I don't know exactly why, but the scaling seems to work for these two sizes although the gap between the buttons doesn't fit anymore. I will experiment with this to figure out the right setting.

Comment: Yes, Please use corrosponding folder for drawables and densities